# django_facebook.middleware.FacebookCanvasMiddleWare error. "NoReverseMatch: u"'admin" is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, openshift, django-facebook

I'm just trying to implement the django_facebook API to a Proof of Concept without success.
I've made the step by step from the README.rest: https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

I'm hosting the POC on **OpenShift**. Info about the virtenv: **Django 1.4v,Python 2.6v**.

The problems occur when I include this sentece on settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
[...]   
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django_facebook.middleware.FacebookCanvasMiddleWare',  **<---**
)
```

I'm stucked.. 
Running the code locally didn't throws error but occurs when **hosting at OpenShift**

[image]

I hope hear from you soon. I need this for the college.
Thanks!

Now... part of my code:

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('metronic.urls', namespace="metronic")),
    #url(r'^facebook/', include('django_facebook.urls')),
    #url(r'^accounts/', include('django_facebook.auth_urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def Default(request):
    #me = request.facebook.graph.get_object('me')
    #access_token = request.facebook.graph.access_token
    #return render(request, 'metronic/Default.html', {'me': me, 'access_token': access_token})
    return render(request, 'metronic/Default.html', {'message': "Hello..."})
```

SETTINGS.PY

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Django settings for openshift project.
import imp, os

# a setting to determine whether we are running on OpenShift
ON_OPENSHIFT = False
if os.environ.has_key('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'):
    ON_OPENSHIFT = True

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    DEBUG = False
else:
    DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    # os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_*'] variables can be used with databases created
    # with rhc cartridge add (see /README in this git repo)
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'], 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR', '')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
#ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make a dictionary of default keys
default_keys = { 'SECRET_KEY': 'vm4rl5*ymb@2&d_(gc$gb-^twq9w(u69hi--%$5xrh!xk(t%hw' }

# Replace default keys with dynamic values if we are in OpenShift
use_keys = default_keys
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    imp.find_module('openshiftlibs')
    import openshiftlibs
    use_keys = openshiftlibs.openshift_secure(default_keys)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = use_keys['SECRET_KEY']

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django_facebook.middleware.FacebookCanvasMiddleWare',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'django_facebook.FacebookProfile'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'openshift.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'metronic',
    'django_facebook',
    'open_facebook',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
FACEBOOK_CANVAS_PAGE = 'https://apps.facebook.com/%s/' % FACEBOOK_APP_ID
FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['publish_stream']
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I added the 500.html to the project and it redirects to admin:index. That's the problem